# Nagios 'exclude' directive does not exclude timeframes

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I tried to set up my nagios install to check the availability of a SMTP service *outside* its backup hours. Unfortunately, it seems to be ignoring this configuration:

```
# a timeperiod to check only outside of zimbra's backup hour
# (combining the first with the second timeperiod)
define timeperiod {
    timeperiod_name     zimbra-backups
    alias               When zimbra is being backed up
    sunday              04:00-05:00
    monday              04:00-05:00
    tuesday             04:00-05:00
    wednesday           04:00-05:00
    thursday            04:00-05:00
    friday              04:00-05:00
    saturday            04:00-05:00
}
define timeperiod {
    timeperiod_name     always-except-zimbra-backups
    alias               24x7 except backup time
        sunday          00:00-24:00
        monday          00:00-24:00
        tuesday         00:00-24:00
        wednesday       00:00-24:00
        thursday        00:00-24:00
        friday          00:00-24:00
        saturday        00:00-24:00
    exclude             zimbra-backups
}
```

Which, then, is used with a new host:

```
define host {
    host_name               mailserver-except-backups
    alias                   mail server (outside backup hours)
    address                 yaddayadda
    notification_options        d,u,r,f
    use                     my-default-host
    check_period            always-except-zimbra-backups
    }
define service {
    host_name                   mailserver-except-backups
    service_description         SMTP service
    check_command               check_smtp!-t 30
    use                         my-default-service
    check_interval              2
    retry_interval              1
    }
```

I can't see what's wrong.. any clue? 
Here is one of the notification e-mail

```
***** Nagios *****

Notification Type: PROBLEM

Service: SMTP service
Host: mail server (outside backup hours)
Address: yaddayadda
State: CRITICAL

Date/Time: Sat Apr 27 04:03:16 CEST 2013

Additional Info:

Connection refused
```

Nagios is Core 3.3.1 running on a OpenBSD 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host checks and service checks are almost entirely unrelated, except for an implicit dependency of the service on its associated host.

You have configured the **host check** for your custom time period, but the service check is using whichever check_period is defined in the template it's using. Add a check_period to your service definition to fix this.

Alternatively, you could use your custom time period as a notification_period for the service, if you just want to suppress notifications during the backup.

Also, not that exclusions **might be broken in 3.3.x**, as noted in this line from the [Nagios version history](http://www.nagios.org/projects/nagioscore/history/core-3x) under 3.2.0:

> Known issue: Service checks that are defined with timeperiods that contain "exclude" directives are incorrectly re-scheduled. Don't use these for now - we'll get this fixed for 3.4

... so you might want to upgrade to 3.4.x or 3.5.0 (latest as of this writing).

Comment: This actually seems to have worked. I'll give it another day to make sure, since mail was sent once a day. Stay tuned ;)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now but I think `check_period` for the service is inherited from `my-default-service` and overrides `check_period` from host definition.

And I also think it is better to suppress only notifications in that interval.

Comment: Well suppressing notifications is not what I want, as other services might require me to receive alerts. I just don't want the SMTP service to be checked in that timeframe.

Comment: I mean suppressing notifications only for SMTP service using notification_period.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should just alter the `notification_period` . You will still get a warning
on your nagios frontend but no notifications will be triggered, during these hours.

Comment: As I already stated in another answer, this is not an acceptable solution.